# iptables port forward between two ips in the same server problems

Tags: iptables, nat, port-forwarding

the server have two IP addresses A and B （default gateway is B）
I want forward port 443 to IP C:443
so I can connect A:443 ----to---c:443

if I use  ( A:443 NAT to C:443) it did not work

```
-A PREROUTING -d A/32  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j  DNAT --to-destination C:443
-A POSTROUTING -d C/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source A:443
```

if I use ( B:443 NAT to C:443) I can connect B:443 but this is not what I want

```
  -A PREROUTING -d B/32  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j  DNAT --to-destination C:443
  -A POSTROUTING -d C/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source B:443
```

and it did not work either even I use ( A:443 NAT to B:443   B:443 to C:443)

```
-A PREROUTING -d A/32  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j  DNAT --to-destination B:443
-A POSTROUTING -d B/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source A:443

-A PREROUTING -d B/32  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j  DNAT --to-destination C:443
-A POSTROUTING -d C/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source B:443
```

so how can I do to make this work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right(if you want to forward port 443 from A to C), you should configure your iptables like this:

```
*nat
-A PREROUTING -d A/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination C:443
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j MASQUERADE
```

Also you should check your iptables configuration for rule `-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited` it disable forwarding at all.
And you should have enabled `net.ipv4.ip_forward` in `sysctl`.

Comment: this does not work ,no reject rule, ip forward has been already enabled

Comment: @cosbeta could you show output for `iptables-save` and `sysctl -a | grep forward` after implementing rules.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8LNyPDPm

Comment: @cosbeta I tried to do it on newly deployed Ubuntu and everything is working. May be issue caused by network interfaces. Could you share your routes?

Comment: default gw is in net B

Comment: @cosbeta I tested this solution on freshly installed Ubuntu 16.4 and it works there. Are you able to access C:443 from host, where you configure iptables?

Comment: I can telnet C:443 from server which has ip addresses A and B, default gw is in B's net, strange problem